# MS-SQL: How can I Filter Database after connecting web hosting

Tags: sql-server, database

I bought a Windows Hosting. I am  connecting the Database Server with my local Sql Server Management.

**My problem is that:** When I connect the Database with my username and password, I see to many database in the Database list. I have only one Database. Other databases belong to other custormers of my Hosting Company. I have to wait for all databases to load in the Object Explorer list. After loading complete, I can start to work on my database. Sometimes its getting a long time.

How can I set my local Sql Server as "***load and show just my database  from Hosting Server and ignore another databases info***"  The screenshot is below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you connect, right-click Databases in Object explorer and from Filter select Filter settings:

[image]

In the dialog, enter "actif" in the row for database name and leave the default "contains" condition. Then when you expand the list of databases, you will see only your database. If there are other databases with "actif" in their name, change the condition to be "equals". Unfortunately, you can't persist this between restarts of SSMS, but you can select to which database to connect in the options of Connect dialog, which may reduce the need to use Object explorer:

[image]

Comment: If you look at OP's screenshot closely or have a similar hosting account, you'll notice the filter button is disabled. Hosting companies generally don't allow database filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest management studio, you should be able to to that.

See this: 
7. Support for filtering in the ‘Databases’ node of SSMS Object Explorer. Navigate to the ‘Databases’ node in Object explorer and click the filter icon in the Object explorer toolbar to filter the list of databases.

[image]

ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-sql-server-management-studio-16-3-august-2016-release/